# I want to hide all email address's from sender by using css or some other way

Tags: jquery, css, email

Is there a way to hide the email address in from field and all email addresses between poster and enquirer in my classifieds site, using css?

Users email each other and, on the site, they can't see the email address of the person they are writing to. But as soon as they send the email, the lister receives the email in their app or off site email inbox, revealing their email address.

I want to hide their email addresses and replace it with code to encode it (random series of letters and numbers)

I tried:

.awpcp-sender-email [title~="example@example.com"] 
   {display: none;}

doesn't work, and the problem may not be the selector itself.

The problem I have is that, when a user emails another, their email appears in the from field and body, and when that person replies, they also reveal their email address.

Privacy reasons are the problem.

Even if it isn't possible with css, possibly with jquery or some other way?

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for answer, below, and forgive me for being a novice, but where and how would I insert that code and can I insert it as it is? Thanks

Comment: I added a information to the my answer.

Comment: OK. Thanks. When I figure out where to find what you mentioned, and when I pluck up the courage to edit my theme directly, I'll see if it works. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Possible with jquery.

```js
$( "div:contains('@example.com')" ).css( "display", "none" );
```

```html
<div>asda@example.com</div>
<div>asdasd</div>
<div>asdasd</div>
<div>aaaaaaaaa@example.com</div>
<div>sdasdasdas</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

You can put of the following codes in anywhere of the site. But it should be between `<body> </ body>` tags.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "div:contains('@example.com')" ).css( "display", "none" );
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can write to me for more help.

Comment: Oh, yes, please, totally lost... Can't I just put it somewhere where I can easily find it and delete it if it doesn't work? I'm using WordPress so would need like literally step by step guide to how to do it. I'm hesitant to mess up my site because if it breaks I don't know how to fix it. That's why I've tried to stick with css - it's easy to find and you can just delete if it doesn't work or something goes wrong.

Comment: I mean css is easy to find because you just put it in the custom css box. I get lost with how to find places where the html is, or where to put it. So if I make an edit to my html, I'll forget where it is or put it in the wrong place or something. Css you always know it's in the custom css box somewhere. Is there something similar to custom css box for html, like a 'custom html' box, or 'custom jquery' box, just so that I always know where to go to edit / delete, or would I have to create child theme to be safe? Thanks.

Comment: I've never used wordpress before. Now I've looked for you but I can't find it :)

Comment: You can ask a new question for that. So you can reach more people.

Comment: Wouldn't it be great, custom html, custom jquery, in a little box, which highlighted all changes I'd made - easily searchable and editable? But I'm dreaming now...

Comment: I found this in my WordPress header php  
    <body <?php body_class(); ?>> is that what you mean by <body>? Thanks

Comment: I tried. It said "Unable to communicate back with site to check for fatal errors, so the PHP change was reverted. You will need to upload your PHP file change by some other means, such as by using SFTP."

Comment: I don't know php :(

Comment: OK. Thanks anyway

Comment: Hi, so I inserted your code after <body <?, the closest thing I could find to <body>, and my site is now not displaying. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: So I deleted it again. Is there any other code? Thanks

Comment: I don't know anything else I can do.

Comment: That was the bottom bit of code. The top two didn't do anything but just displayed on the front end of my home page.

Comment: OK. No probs, Thanks. BTW, is <body <? The same as <body>, because I inserted after <body <?

Comment: No. It just stopped my site from being visible

Comment: Thanks for trying though